# Object reference in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

I'm having one form and two user control like these:

```cs
public MyServerForm(ApplicationInstance application)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    m_application = application; //Let's call this m_app

    myServerDesignerUC = new MyServerDesignerUC(m_application);
    myServerStatusUC = new MyServerStatusUC(m_application);
}
```

```cs
public MyServerDesignerUC(ApplicationInstance application)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    m_application = application; //Let's call this m_app1
}
```

```cs
public MyServerStatusUC(ApplicationInstance application)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    m_application = application; //Let's call this m_app2
    m_server = m_application.Server as StandardServer;
    m_configuration = m_application.ApplicationConfiguration;
}
```

m_application is the private field declared in each class. In my `Program.cs` `Main`, I call the constructor of MyServerForm: `MyServerForm(ApplicationInstance application)`.
I supposed the `application`, `m_app`, `m_app1`, `m_app2` are all referencing to the same instance, and any change in one of them will result to change of all others. But when I change `m_app1`, the `m_app2`still remain.

I did some research and got answer like `m_app1` and `m_app` reference to the same instance, `m_app2` and `m_app` reference to the same instance, but `m_app1` and `m_app2` do not directly reference to each other. Sound weird to me.
So if I want all of them reference to an unique instance. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change m_app1"? *How* did you change it? If you assigned another reference to it, then of course the other variables won't be updated with the new reference.

Comment: _m_application is the private field declared in each class._ So each class has three local variables and _initially_ you set them to the same application reference, but if you assign a different instance, of whatever application is, to one of them the other variables are not aware of this change

Comment: @Steve: Fields, not local variables.

Answer (score 2):

> I supposed the application, m_app, m_app1, m_app2 are all referencing to the same instance, and any change in one of them will result to change of all others.

No - any modification of the *object* that the variables values refer to will indeed be seen through any of the variables. But the variables themselves are independent - assigning a different value to one of the variables does nothing to the others.

Think about it this way: if multiple people, each with their own physical addressbook, all have a physical address for me. If one of them uses their addressbook to find my house and paint my front door green, then any of the other people will see a green front door if they use *their* addressbook to find my house. But if one of them just changes their addressbook (e.g. because I've told that person that I've moved house, but not the others) then that doesn't change the addressbooks of anyone else.

Note that this isn't in any way specific to Windows Forms - this is just how .NET works with reference types.

Comment: _"this is just how .NET works with reference types"_ - and similar concepts in other languages, too.

Comment: @Fildor: In many cases, yes - but I try to avoid overgeneralizing as that often end up with someone adding a comment 10 years later saying "But *XYZ* language works differently..."

Comment: That's true, yes. Just wanted to point out that this isn't even specific to .NET, only.